# How do professional statisticians evaluate or mathematically justify choice of one smoothing method from another?

Tags: regression, model-evaluation, smoothing, noise

I would like to fit some economic data and evaluate it. Usually I used only regression techniques, but recently I found out about smoothing techniques which could be used to diminish noise in dataset before regression. As I currently understand, conventional way for assessment of a fitting (pre-processed by smoothing) is to calculate common parameters of a regressive model as R-squared, Bayesian information criteria and etc.
However, I could not find proper methodology for choice of smoothing technique standalone. I mean some statistical parameter which could be used to assess choice of onesmoothing method over another. Is it possible to evaluate choice of smoothing method before processing with regression?

To provide the context, let me say that I want to "clean" dataset with moving average.
For example, I take averaging across 2, 3 or 5 recent dataset points. How to assess accuracy of choice of one type of moving average over another independently from usual regression?